# How to use the Model in the currect way - sequelize with typescript

Tags: sql, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

Here is my sequelize model -

```
import { BuildOptions, DataTypes, Model, Sequelize } from "sequelize";

import { IDBUserAttributes } from "./shared/db-table";

    interface UserModel extends Model<IDBUserAttributes>, IDBUserAttributes {}
    
    class User extends Model<UserModel, IDBUserAttributes> {}
    
    type UserStatic = typeof Model & {
      new (values?: object, options?: BuildOptions): UserModel;
    };
    
    const UserFactory = (sequelize: Sequelize): UserStatic => {
      return <UserStatic>sequelize.define("users", {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true,
          unique: true,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(320),
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true,
        },
        username: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(26),
          allowNull: false,
        },
        password: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
          allowNull: false,
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
          allowNull: false,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },
        updatedAt: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
          allowNull: false,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
        },
      });
    }
    
    export {
      UserModel,
      User,
      UserFactory,
      UserStatic,
    }
```

I want to use the model in the controllers. For example like this -
`User.create()` or any other method.

How can i get the model?
..................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing sequelize js and sequelize ts. I never used sequelize with vanilla js but I think you don't need the UserFactory. The class should be enough to instantiate your model and to create it.

A simple class should look like something like that :

```
@Table({ modelName: 'users' })
export class UserModel extends Model {
  @Column({ primaryKey: true, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER })
  idUser: number;

  @Column({ type: DataTypes.STRING })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ type: DataTypes.STRING })
  lastName: string;
}
```

You can describe all your columns as properties of your class with the @Column and by giving some parameters to this annotation.

Then you just need to import (or inject depending of your framework) in your code and you can use all the method of the class.

In my case it will look like

```
UserModel.create(params)
```

For more details you can find the doc here:
https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript#model-definition